# How do you use "n" to switch your version of Node?

Tags: macos, node.js

I use a Mac.  I just ran "n latest" to install the latest version of Node.

Now I want to activate it, but am getting an error "File exists" when trying to make a symlink.  What does this mean? How do I fix it?

When I run "which node" I see node installed at /usr/bin/node.

```
My-Comp:~ myuser$ n latest
cp: symlink: ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js: File exists
My-Comp:~ myuser$ n ls
    0.0.1
    0.0.2
    0.0.3
    0.0.4
    0.0.5
    0.0.6
    0.1.0
    0.1.1
    0.1.2
    0.1.3
    0.1.4
    0.1.5
    0.1.6
    0.1.7
    0.1.8
    0.1.9
    0.1.10
    0.1.11
    0.1.12
    0.1.13
    0.1.14
    0.1.15
    0.1.16
    0.1.17
    0.1.18
    0.1.19
    0.1.20
    0.1.21
    0.1.22
    0.1.23
    0.1.24
    0.1.25
    0.1.26
    0.1.27
    0.1.28
    0.1.29
    0.1.30
    0.1.31
    0.1.32
    0.1.33
    0.1.90
    0.1.91
    0.1.92
    0.1.93
    0.1.94
    0.1.95
    0.1.96
    0.1.97
    0.1.98
    0.1.99
    0.1.100
    0.1.101
    0.1.102
    0.1.103
    0.1.104
    0.2.0
    0.2.1
    0.2.2
    0.2.3
    0.2.4
    0.2.5
    0.2.6
    0.3.0
    0.3.1
    0.3.2
    0.3.3
    0.3.4
    0.3.5
    0.3.6
    0.3.7
    0.3.8
    0.4.0
    0.4.1
    0.4.2
    0.4.3
    0.4.4
    0.4.5
    0.4.6
    0.4.7
    0.4.8
    0.4.9
    0.4.10
  ο 0.4.11 
    0.4.12
    0.5.0
    0.5.1
    0.5.2
    0.5.3
    0.5.4
    0.5.5
    0.5.6
    0.5.7
    0.5.8
    0.5.9
    0.5.10
    0.6.0
    0.6.1
    0.6.2
    0.6.3
    0.6.4
    0.6.5
    0.6.6
    0.6.7
    0.6.8
    0.6.9
    0.6.10
    0.6.11
    0.6.12
    0.6.13
    0.6.14
    0.6.15
    0.6.16
    0.6.17
    0.6.18
    0.6.19
    0.6.20
    0.7.0
    0.7.1
    0.7.2
    0.7.3
    0.7.4
    0.7.5
    0.7.6
    0.7.7
    0.7.8
    0.7.9
    0.7.10
    0.7.11
    0.7.12
    0.8.0
    0.8.1
    0.8.2
  * 0.8.3
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo rm /usr/local/bin/npm`

...should clear out the offending left-over symlink from an old node/npm install and allow n to finish installing.